# Accuracy of LODES dataset

Tags: us-census, census

Has anyone used the LEHD Origin-Destination Employment Statistics (LODES) datasets? I'm using the data from the [Census FTP](http://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/) for LODES7 data. I want to understand how this data was calculated and what's the accurancy. Since, most of the census data comes with a margin of error (MOE), I assume this data also has some MOE but not mentioned in the tables.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the data at http://www.census.gov/ces/dataproducts/lehddata.html and http://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/LODESTechDoc7.2.pdf ?

Comment: Thanks @Skram. Tech Doc has the info about the data and it's constituents but no info about how the data was developed. I'm current going through the doc https://www2.census.gov/ces/wp/2014/CES-WP-14-26.pdf. I'll update if I find anything useful. Thanks!